# Custom application error messages not working when using Waffle

Tags: java, spring-security, waffle

I have Waffle in a Java Spring Boot application.

When I throw a custom error, such as the one below, Waffle gets in the middle and sends a different error message to the caller.

`throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`

That should return a 404 BAD REQUEST message to the caller.

But instead, it returns a 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.

At the IDE console it displays the following message when the custom error message is thrown:

`Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid Authorization header: Negotiate`

Here is the code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter;

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint entryPoint;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
          http
            .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(negotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)                
                .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));  
         
        http.cors();         
                
    }
    
    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {      
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
    }
    
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class WaffleConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public WindowsAuthProviderImpl waffleWindowsAuthProvider() {
        return new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider(
            WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {
        return new NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider(
            WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {
        return new BasicSecurityFilterProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterProviderCollection waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection(
            NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider,
            BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider) {
        SecurityFilterProvider[] securityFilterProviders =
                {negotiateSecurityFilterProvider, basicSecurityFilterProvider};
        return new SecurityFilterProviderCollection(securityFilterProviders);
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint(
            SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
        NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint =
                new NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint();
        negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
        return negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter(
            SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
        NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter = new NegotiateSecurityFilter();
        negotiateSecurityFilter.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
        return negotiateSecurityFilter;
    }

    // This is required for Spring Boot so it does not register the same filter twice
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean waffleNegotiateSecurityFilterRegistration(
            NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

}
```